# Why is my WCF response so slow transfering 1MB of data

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net

I've been working on this for quite a few hours now and have not found any solutions to what I am experiencing.

I am serializing a list of 3000 DTOs via protobuf with basicHttpBinding. I can see that WCF is indeed sending the  node with the encoded data along. The problem is, this response is about 1 MB in size and it taking 30 seconds to complete once I step through the last method in the call. If I do a .take(100) on the list the response takes about 1-2 seconds, and .take(1) is instant.

I tried manually serializing the 3000 record list to a memory stream with protobuf and it was nearly instantaneous which leads me to believe it has something to do with the transfering of data.

This is replicable on any machine the service and site are ran on. Any ideas?

Comment: is MTOM enabled (and if not, can it be)? that would reduce bandwidth a little; however, I'm having difficulty mapping your description to code (at least, in an unambiguous way) - any chance of any code here?

Comment: If you can transfer 100 items in 1 second and 3000 items in 30 seconds then at least it's consistent :) Seriously, though, have you tried sending over the memory stream instead?

Answer (score 0):

While prototyping to compare WCF to some other technologies, we came across a similar problem. We thought we had configured WCF to use protobuf-net to serialize, but it wasn't working correctly. The most head-frying thing for me was that *there was no error*, WCF just silently defaulted to the DataContractSerializer. DataContractSerializer will either serialize in binary or XML depending on the WCF binding used. For basicHTTPBinding it will serialize to XML, which will of course result in a large and slow response.

I suggest that you verify that WCF is really serializing using protobuf-net. You should be able to see if this is happening by peeking inside the packets with wireshark (or similar tool).

Hope this helps <333